# Tell user in ios with a Tableview that the most recent call to server did not get any data

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uitableview

I am making a call (with AFNetworking) to a server. When I get that data, I put it into an array and call refresh the screen. So far, so good. But what I'm not sure how to do is with asynchronous calls to a server tell the user (in, say, a cell) that there is no data to display. AND when there is data to display, get rid of a "No Data to display" cells.

Using ios 6.1, but would like to support ios 5.

Comment: Are you only making one call to the server? Or is something where each cell represents a separate call to the server? And you could potentially have say the 1st cells data back while the 2nd cell is still waiting for a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'd like a way of showing a 'no data to display' message if there are no results, and then replace that when data is available.

My approach is generally to display a loading indicator (overlaid over the table view) to the user when I start loading the content (i.e. when first making the call to the server). You can have a flag on your controller that tracks whether you're currently loading data - set this to YES when you start loading, and then NO when loading completes. While loading, you can simply not display any cells in your table (assuming you have some other display to show the user that it's loading). E.g.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if (isLoading) return 0; //Don't display any cells while loading

   if (modelArray.count == 0) return 1; //1 row for the cell indicating there's no data

   return modelArray.count; //1 row for each entry in array
}
```

When the server returns data, remove the loading indicator and refresh the table view data.

When no data is returned, presumably your model array will be empty. Simply check for this case in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in your UITableViewDataSource, and if the array is empty, return a cell with a message indicating that there's no data, e.g.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (modelArray.count == 0)
    {
        return noResultsMessageCell;
    }
    else
    {
        <normal cell dequeueing code>
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing something like this. First, I would prefer not to have a cell that says something like "no results" while the data is being downloaded. But it's annoyingly difficult to get this. Second, and more importantly, once you create the cell that says no more data do you have to get rid of that cell?

Comment: I've updated my answer - basically you conditionally return either the no results cell or the normal list of cells, but not both. You can control how many appear with `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`